# What folders and files gets backed up through iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, jailbreak

Everytime I get a call my old wallpaper shows even though I have a new one. I'm trying to find it on my iOS but I cannot seem to figure out where. So I'm trying to track down what folders gets backed up when i backup my iPhone since I have restored it and it's still there.
(I'm using a jailbroken device)

Comment: Are you synchronizing a folder that contains the wallpaper or was there a folder synched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manually managed to find out what gets backed up and managed to solve the problem :)
I downloaded the trial of iphone packup extractor http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/ and found what I was looking for.

Also it seems like I just had to change the lockscreen in the iPhone since the file called LockScreen.jpg was the picture I was looking for but since I had another lockscreen using winterboard I didnt think of this.

Good luck to anyone else who has problems similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

All user documents and settings get backed up, Application settings as well as system settings.

Applications each have a Documents folder that user data can be saved to, so thats pretty much what gets backed up for applications, including app preferences.

These are the Wallpaper locations:

```
/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/HomeBackground.jpg
/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/HomeBackgroundPortrait.jpg
/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/LockBackground.jpg
/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/LockBackgroundPortrait.jpg
```

Comment: Do you have any thought where this particular image might be saved?

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't the actual folder names and etc but it will give you an idea what it's backing up though. Good Luck.

**With iOS 1.1 and later**

- Safari bookmarks, cookies, history,
  and currently open pages
- Map bookmarks, recent searches, and
  the current location displayed in
  Maps
- Application settings, preferences,
  and data
- Address Book and Address Book
  favorites
- Calendar accounts
- Wallpapers
- Notes
- Call history
- Mail accounts
- YouTube bookmarks
- SMS messages
- Saved suggestion corrections (these
  are saved automatically as you reject
  suggested corrections)
- Camera Roll (photos and screenshots
  taken by the iPhone)
- Voicemail token (This is not the
  Voicemail password, but is used for
  validation when connecting. This is
  only restored to a phone with the
  same phone number on the SIM card.)
- Web clips
- Network settings (saved Wi-Fi
  hotspots, VPN settings, network
  preferences)
- Paired Bluetooth devices (which can
  only be used if restored to the same
  phone that created the backup)
- Keychain (this includes email account
  passwords, Wi-Fi passwords, and
  passwords you enter into websites and
  some other applications. The keychain
  can only be restored from backup to
  the same iPhone or iPod touch. If you
  are restoring to a new device, you
  will need to fill in these passwords
  again.)

**With iOS 2.0 and later (in addition to the above)**

- Managed Configurations/Profiles
- List of External Sync Sources (Mobile Me, Exchange ActiveSync)
- Microsoft Exchange account configurations
- Nike + iPod saved workouts and settings
- App Store application data (except the application itself, its tmp and caches folder).

**With iOS 3.0 and later (in addition to the above)**

- Videos in Camera Roll
- Per app preferences allowing use of location services
- Offline web application cache/database
- Voice Memos
- Autofill for webpages
- Trusted hosts having certificates that cannot be verified
- Websites approved to get the location of the device
- In-app purchases

**New with iOS 3.1:** Videos in the Camera Roll that are 2 GB or larger are not backed up (iOS 4 and later will back up videos 2 GB and larger)